# Unable to Update child element in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

Unable to update 2 level and 3 level nested form attributes. I can update 1 level attributes but don't know why it's not updating.

**below is my code**

```
  def update
    @buyer.update_attributes(params[:buyer])
    if params[:id].to_i != 0 
      redirect_to wizard_path(:buyer_posting_params)
    else
      render_wizard @buyer
    end
  end
```

**Below is my params**

> "buyer"=>{"buyer_forms_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"buyer_posting_params_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"13",
>   "_destroy"=>"false", "param_name"=>"11", "param_type"=>"dynamic",
>   "param_value"=>"", "question_id"=>"17"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"14",
>   "_destroy"=>"false", "param_name"=>"22", "param_type"=>"dynamic",
>   "param_value"=>"", "question_id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"17",
>   "_destroy"=>"false", "param_name"=>"33", "param_type"=>"static",
>   "param_value"=>"test", "question_id"=>""}}, "id"=>"4"},
>   "1"=>{"buyer_posting_params_attributes"=>{"1413443012516"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
>   "param_name"=>"22", "param_type"=>"dynamic", "param_value"=>"",
>   "question_id"=>"24"}}, "id"=>"44"}}}

I'm using Rails 3.2

Relationship like :

```
One Buyer HasMany BuyerForms
One BuyerForm HasMany BuyerPostingParams
```

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you accept nested attributes? If not, this may help you:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
# buyer.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :buyer_forms

# buyer_form.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :buyer_posting_params
```